# How to create Python API or network requests hidden (protected from hackers checking network traffic) on Local Network to manage Computers

Tags: python, windows, api, python-requests

I know that I can see inside of network traffic for example with WireShark. When i use GET on HTML I can see those stuff in URL, what should not be problem what I am doing. But I believe GET,POST and maybe REQUEST too, as I did not work with that one yet can bee seen on something like Wire Shark network analyzer.

I am making Python client, what i will put on computers in network to show their IP,Host Name and Users on PC. This client will be as gate to the computer for remote control. As our management does not want to spend money for windows server, or other management system we need to get something free to manage all computers.

I am also seeking advice how I could do it as you are more skilled then me here.
I found few ways.

1. With the client create SSH Gateway for receiving commands.
2. With Client enable the Powershell remote option, then just push scripts to all computers at once.
3. Use some way the API requests etc... I am not skilled in this one at all, but I believe this is the way how other similar programs works?

As this client would create big security risk, I am first seeking way what is best way to hide it from network. Probably I will need to come up with some Private and public Key system here as well.

What are yours suggestions please on this topic?
here is just very short code I am playing with to receive basic info as IP, Host name and all Users
the Flask website showing those values is just for test, It will not be there once it is deployed

**Update**
I took advice from `MarulForFlask` but I got a couple issues. First this i think can have only one connection at a time. And second if possible Can i get the output of console from the client PC on screen of Server PC?
I want this output only for testing, as I know if i do something like netstat or any other command with multiple clients it would filled up screen with too many text... Currently I am getting back text format as plaintext with \r \n ... and other text deviders.

I am now trying Multicast, but i am getting error for binding the multicast IP.
`OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context`

**Master.py**

```
import time 
import socket 
import sys 
import os 
valueExit = True

# Initialize s to socket 
s = socket.socket() 

# Initialize the host 
host = socket.gethostname() 

BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
# Initialize the port 
port = 8080

# Bind the socket with port and host 
s.bind(('', port)) 

print("waiting for connections...") 

# listening for conections 
s.listen() 

# accepting the incoming connections 
conn, addr = s.accept() 

print(addr, "is connected to server") 
def send_query(): 
    keepAllive, repeatIt = True, False
    print("""To exit session write:    EndSession
    For help write:   help
    """)

    while (keepAllive == True):
        # commands for server use only
        innerCommands = ["endsession", "help"]
        # take command as input 
        command = input(str("Enter Command : "))     
        
        
        if command not in innerCommands:

            conn.send(command.encode()) 

            print("Command has been sent successfully.") 
            keepAllive = False        
            repeatIt = True

        elif (command == "endsession"):
            conn.send(command.encode()) 
            valueExit = False            

        elif (command == "help"):
            print("""To exit session write:    EndSession""")
            

    while (repeatIt == True):
        # recieve the confrmation 
        data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE) 

        if data: 
            print(f"command recieved and executed sucessfully.\n {data}") 
            keepAllive = True
            repeatIt = False
            
        else:
            print("No reply from computer")
            keepAllive = True
            repeatIt = False

while  valueExit == True:
    send_query()
```

**Slave.py**

```
import time 
import socket 
import sys
import subprocess
import os


stayOn = True
def establishConnection():
    # Initialize s to socket
    s = socket.socket()

    # Initialize the host
    host = "127.0.0.1"

    # Initiaze the port
    port = 8080

    keepAlive = True

    try:
        # bind the socket with port and host
        s.connect((host, port))
        print("Connected to Server.")
        while keepAlive == True:
            # recieve the command from master program
            command = s.recv(1024)
            command = command.decode()
            # match the command and execute it on slave system

            if command == "endsession":
                print("Program Ended")
                keepAlive = False
            elif command != "":
                # print("Command is :", command)
                #s.send("Command recieved".encode())

                proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
                (out, err) = proc.communicate()
                s.send(f"{out}".encode())
                print("program output:", out)




    except Exception as err:
        print(f"Error: {err}")
        s.send(f"Error: {err}".encode())


while stayOn == True:
    establishConnection()
```

Comment: You cannot protect code that runs in an unsecured environment. This is true for any programming language. It's just a lot easier to reverse engineer Python code and compromise the system. Ultimately, you get for what you pay for. You decided to not pay anything and get security implemented by what's not even a junior developer.

Answer (score 0):

see:
https://www.pythonforthelab.com/blog/how-to-control-a-device-through-the-network/

There uses a flask webserver.

otherwise, create a master.py file and paste this code:

```
import time 
import socket 
import sys 
import os 
  
# Initialize s to socket 
s = socket.socket() 
  
# Initialize the host 
host = socket.gethostname() 
  
# Initialize the port 
port = 8080
  
# Bind the socket with port and host 
s.bind(('', port)) 
  
print("waiting for connections...") 
  
# listening for conections 
s.listen() 
  
# accepting the incoming connections 
conn, addr = s.accept() 
  
print(addr, "is connected to server") 
  
# take command as input 
command = input(str("Enter Command :")) 
  
conn.send(command.encode()) 
  
print("Command has been sent successfully.") 
  
# recieve the confrmation 
data = conn.recv(1024) 
  
if data: 
    print("command recieved and executed sucessfully.")
```

open a slave.py and paste this code:

```
import time 
import socket 
import sys 
import os 
  
# Initialize s to socket 
s = socket.socket() 
  
# Initialize the host 
host = "127.0.0.1"
  
# Initiaze the port 
port = 8080
  
# bind the socket with port and host 
s.connect((host, port)) 
  
print("Connected to Server.") 
  
# recieve the command from master program 
command = s.recv(1024) 
command = command.decode() 
  
# match the command and execute it on slave system 
if command == "open": 
    print("Command is :", command) 
    s.send("Command recieved".encode()) 
      
    # you can give batch file as input here 
    os.system('ls')
```

open slave.py in client, master.py in server

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-control-pc-from-anywhere-using-python/

Comment: Thank you, looks interesting. Can you advice this this is clear text TCP communication, right? I will need to use encryption to hide content.